# DocuSign JWT Grant flow gives an "invalid_grant" error

Tags: docusignapi

Has anyone experienced the invalid_grant error mentioned in the subject here that gets an error calling ApiClient.RequestJWTUserToken  ?

Here's my call. I've verified that I have values for my DSConfig fields.

```
private void UpdateToken()
    {
        ApiClient docusign_api = new ApiClient();
        DSConfig cfg = new DSConfig();
        const int jwtLifeSec = 10 * 60; // requested lifetime 
//for the JWT     is     10 min
        List<string> scopes = new List<string>();
            scopes.Add("signature");
 // impersonation scope is implied due to use of JWT grant

    OAuth.OAuthToken authToken = docusign_api.RequestJWTUserToken    (DSConfig.ClientID,
                    DSConfig.ImpersonatedUserGuid,
                    DSConfig.AuthServer,
                    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(DSConfig.PrivateKey),
                    jwtLifeSec, scopes);

        AccessToken = authToken.access_token;

        if (Account == null)
            Account = GetAccountInfo(authToken);

        docusign_api = new ApiClient(Account.BaseUri + "/restapi");

        expiresIn = DateTime.Now.Second + authToken.expires_in.Value;
    }

public OAuth.OAuthToken RequestJWTUserToken(string clientId, string userId, string oauthBasePath, byte[] privateKeyBytes, int expiresInHours, List<string> scopes = null);
```

Comment: what value you are passing in DSConfig.AuthServer param?

Comment: I am using https://account-d.docusign.com as the AuthServer

Comment: Normally we get invalid_grant when any input parameter is invalid in the call, can you try by creating token outside code using website like [JWT](https://jwt.io/) with payload will look like `{
 "iss": "IntegratorKey",
 "sub": "UserId",
 "iat": 1536700971,
 "exp": 1536704571,
 "aud": "account-d.docusign.com",
 "scope": "impersonation signature"
}`

Comment: and then use PostMan to do `POST` call to `https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token` with req body as `grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=jwtassertioncreatedfromjwt.iowebsite` and `Content-Type` will be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: I changed my AuthServer parameter and am no longer getting the invalid_grant. I am now getting 'consent_required'. Should I be using the API Account user for the impersonatedUserGUID?

Comment: What you change AuthServer param to? and Consent_Required error means that your IntegratorKey did not get explicit consent from the user - ImpersonatedUserGuid to impersonate this user. [Obtaining Consent](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/obtaining-consent) explains how to get consent.

Comment: @AmitKBist - I removed the https:// from the authServer I had specified. I never get prompted to give consent as the ImpersonatedUser.

Comment: You have to create that URL to get the consent on your IntegratorKey from the user for whom you are planning to generate an AccessToken using JWT with impersonation scope, please check the documentation link which I posted in my last comment to get the User Consent. Consent URL for Demo env would be like `https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=impersonation signature&client_id=Your_Integrator_Key&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI_SAME_AS_CONFIGURED_IN_INTEGRATORKEY`

Comment: @AmitKBist I am facing the exact same issue ("invalid_grant") for the exact same code. I have also provided the user consent that is needed. Is there anything specific that needs to be done in the "API and Keys" section of the docusign admin console in addition to setting up the client_id, redirectUI and private key? Any help in this regard would be deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: when you copy pasted PrivateKey, I hope you have copy pasted as-is, without removing ----- (dashes) and no formatting done by you. If yes, then try to generate JWT Assertion using [JWT](https://jwt.io/) website, and make sure to select RS256 in Algorithm dropdown. You can use [EpochConverter](https://www.epochconverter.com/) wesbite to generate iat and exp attribute value of the payload. I have already shared payload structure in my early comments. Once JWT assertion is created then use POSTMAN to generate AccessToken, this detail is also available in my early comments.

Comment: @AmitKBist Thanks! I am able to generate the access token on PostMan using the links that you suggested. So, looks like the integrator key settings in DocuSign are working as expected. Its the code that is failing. The method "RequestJWTUserToken" seems to be failing  with the "invalid_grant" error. What could be the issue here? I copied the private key as is without removing the "BEGIN" and "END" phrases. First time, I got a "END RSA Private key not found error". I had to manually insert line feed characters into the key.... contd.

Comment: ...This seemed to work so far as to generate the token using the RSA algorithm, but the API started returning the "invalid_grant" error. Could it be the private key that is the issue? @AmitKBist

Comment: Generate Token using RSA Algorithm means? using jwt.io website and Postman you are able to successfully generate AccessToken but not via Code?

Comment: @mantadt Make sure that the oAuthBasePath parameter is 'account-d.docusign.com' and does not have the protocol (http or https) included. Also, I made sure the clientID parameter was the Integrator Key.

Comment: Yes Morgs, I have used "account-d.docusign.com" as the oAuthBasePath and have verified that the clientID is the integrator key. Still, no luck. @AmitKBist Yep, I am able to generate it through postman, but not through code. By the RSA algorithm, I meant that it is able to process the private key and move forward, but isn't able to get the correct output from the auth api. I validated this by looking at the internals of the method on github(lines 1071 to 1075). https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/sdk/src/DocuSign.eSign/Client/ApiClient.cs

Comment: If its working fine with Postman then something is wrong in how you are loading the PrivateKey in your code, can you try to load with `File.ReadAllBytes` method?

Comment: Yes @AmitKBist. Tried everything. It didn't work. I had to clone the DocuSign.eSign repo and debug the code. The problem was that it was generating an extra "nbf" claim in my JWT token, which the DocuSign Auth Server didn't like. Once, I removed this claim, it worked. So, now I have a custom version of the DocuSign.eSign.dll

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not using the right arguments.

The third argument is the `scopes` parameter, not the server.

For Node.js, try this:

```
const jwtLifeSec = 10 * 60, // requested lifetime for the JWT is 10 min
      scopes = "signature", // impersonation scope is implied due to use of JWT grant
      dsApi = new docusign.ApiClient();

dsApi.setOAuthBasePath(dsConfig.authServer);
const results = await dsApi.requestJWTUserToken(dsConfig.clientId,
      dsConfig.impersonatedUserGuid, scopes, dsConfig.privateKey,
      jwtLifeSec);
```

Comment: Here's the method signature for the version I have:

        //     The JWT user token
        public OAuth.OAuthToken RequestJWTUserToken(string clientId, string userId, string oauthBasePath, Stream privateKeyStream, int expiresInHours, List<string> scopes = null);

Comment: Oh, are you using Java? My example is for Node. Please EDIT your question to include your code. Code in a comment does not really help. Thank you.

Comment: I'm using C# .Net framework. I have a web forms application that I am trying to integrate the embedded signing into. The only piece I do not have working yet is the JWT Auth. Updated code in initial question